# NaN Value, First characters in string

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Using Python and dataframe module:

```
df

|ID
|250000.9T1.008  
|821000.9S1.006  
|352300.144
```

---

Using python 3, I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe that takes the first 6 characters from the ID column.  I'm using the following line of code to do so:

```
df['ID1'] = df['ID'].str[:6]
```

Result:

```
|ID               |ID1
|250000.9T1.008   |250000   
|821000.9S1.006   |821000  
|352300.144       |NaN
```

My guess is there is some data type issue with the 3rd ID since it doesn't contain a letter maybe it is read as an int?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
df['ID1'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:6])
```